# How can I get an ID if I need a passport when I also need a ID to get a passport?

Tags: passports, us-citizens

I was born in Korea, so I can’t show proof of US citizenship through a birth certificate. My US passport just expired late last year. I never got a proof of citizenship because I was a dependent just until late last year. The problem is, to renew my passport, I need identification, but I don’t have a drivers license. So they told me I needed to get an ID. So, I went in to a DPS and tried to get an ID, but they told me I needed an unexpired passport. I’m kind of stuck in the middle. Is there any way that I can one or the either some way.

Comment: Could you clarify which country's passport you're trying to renew? And can you confirm that that country's passport office isn't accepting your expired passport as evidence of citizenship? (Many countries do. I can't tell from your question if the passport office told you that your expired passport is no good, or if you just assumed it would be no good so didn't even try to use it.)

Comment: The DPS told me that an expired passport is no good to get an Identification card. I have tried to get both (not assumed).

Comment: What's a DPS?  What state or city do you live in?  Most people can come up with adequate ID from the secondary ID list.  Do you have a consular report of birth abroad?

Comment: I second that: You had to have a consular report of birth abroad in order to get the original passport.

Comment: It’s the Texas department of public safety. You go there to get drivers’ permits and licenses, as well as an identification card which you will need after you turn 18 if you don’t have a license, as school ID will no longer be enough for places like airports. And my birth certificate doesn’t work because it’s Korean and doesn’t prove American citizenship. Also, first generation immigrant, I got my citizenship after 7 years, I moved to the US when I was 2 so the consensus report of birth abroad doesn’t apply. Sorry for not being that clear in my original question

Comment: The certificate of birth abroad issued by the US consulate when you were born does prove it. Unless you're trying to say you are a naturalized citizen.

Comment: Thanks for addressing my questions.  Were you naturalized or did you become a citizen automatically when your parents naturalized?  If the former, you could use your naturalization certificate, of course, but I suppose it is the latter so you don't have one.  You also do not necessarily need a non-driver ID to fly, of course; you can use your passport once you have one.  @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas since OP became a citizen "after seven years" and moved to the US at age 2, I think it is clear that he was not a citizen at birth, so does not have a CRBA.

Comment: @phoog There's nothing indicating that in the question. Just that they have a Korean cert and never bothered getting a "proof of citizenship" while a minor.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I was referring to the [comment posted immediately before yours](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133718/how-can-i-get-an-id-if-i-need-a-passport-when-i-also-need-a-id-to-get-a-passport?noredirect=1#comment331995_133718): ", first generation immigrant, I got my citizenship after 7 years, I moved to the US when I was 2..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The US Department of State [says](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/apply-in-person.html) that, if you're applying in person for a new passport, a "fully-valid, undamaged U.S. passport (may be expired)" is enough to prove US citizenship, and a "valid or expired, undamaged U.S. passport book or passport card" is accepted as ID.

Comment: It appears that the question is more about proof of identity than about proof of citizenship, despite mention of the latter.

Comment: @phoog Good point. But the expired passport is good as ID, too. (Edited.)

Comment: I wonder what they mean by "fully valid ... may be expired."

Comment: Yep. Renew the passport, and then you have rock-solid unexpired ID that you can use for most other purposes, including to get other ID.

Comment: @phoog Presumably, "valid" means that it's not been revoked or something. But I'm not sure why they use different wording to describe what's needed for a passport to be used as proof of citizenship and as ID.